# How do I make ssh ask for the password every time?

Tags: ssh, 22.04, openssh

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. This is an unusual question since most users want to make the ssh agent remember the password once it is entered per user session. I would like it to **ask for the password every time I am using ssh** (mostly for git pull and push purposes). I have tried to set

```
Host *
     AddKeysToAgent no
```

to my `~/.ssh/config` file. I have checked that the `.bashrc` is not storing the password in an environment variable. Can anyone please help me make ssh ask for the passphrase every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

Open a terminal.

Edit the SSH configuration file.

```
 sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the line containing the PasswordAuthentication directive in the sshd_config file, make sure the line is the following:

```
 PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save your changes and close the text editor, pressing Ctrl+O to save and then Ctrl+X to exit.

Restart the SSH service for the changes to take effect:

```
  sudo service ssh restart
```

Now, every time you connect to an SSH server from your system it should ask for the password of the remote user you are trying to access.

Comment: This didn't work :( I even rebooted after making these changes. Any given repo asks for the password once, and then not again.